# Using page query with python

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, map-series, cartographic-information-model, page-query

I am trying to automate a process in ArcGIS pro using python. In this process I create several maps using a map series. I use a page query to filter my data based on the map series page name.

I can't figure out how to turn on the page query using python.

Is there any way to use page queries with a python function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Python CIM access as described below. A handy way to see what you want to update is to set it manually, then export the layer to lyrx and open the lyrx in a notepad to view the JSON.

```
## access your aprx
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")

## access the layout
layout = aprx.listLayouts("Layout Name")[0] # update your layout name

## access the mapframe
mapframe = layout.listElements ("MAPFRAME_ELEMENT", "MapFrame Name")[0] # update your mapframe name

## access the layer to update Page Query for
lyr = mapframe.map.listLayers("Layer Name")[0] # update your layer name

## get the CIM definition (like JSON)
lyr_cim = lyr.getDefinition('V3') 

## update the pageDefinition
lyr_cim.pageDefinition = {"type" : "CIMPageDefinition","pageFieldName" : "FIELD NAME", "excludePages" : False} # update FIELD NAME, set excludePages to True or False

## update the lyr CIM definition
lyr.setDefinition(lyr_cim)

## save your aprx
aprx.save()
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Allthough i had to remove the ' "excludePages" : False ' part of the code. Looking at the lyrx file was a good suggestion.

Comment: Great stuff. excludePages is probably only needed if you are setting to True. Thanks for the feedback.